Data not ordered properly in lockless spsc queue
I'm trying to write a bounded lockless single-producer, single-consumer queue, however, the order of elements inserted into the queue is not the same as the order of the elements removed from the queue. The test code in main.cpp adds 100,000,000 sequential ints to the queue in one thread, and pops the values in another, checking that the values are sequential.
Currently, the when running the program, it prints "Oh no! last value was: 219718 but this value is 220231" (the number values differ between program runs). The range of the numbers seems to depend on yield_frequency in writer_thread, lower values of yield_frequency cause the test to (often, but not always) fail at a number in the 100s.
(The code is a wip so there's probably some code that doesn't match c++ best practices)
spsc_queue.hpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <bit>
#include <atomic>
#include <optional>

template <typename T> class ChannelReader;
template <typename T> class ChannelWriter;

// instances of this class cannot be created directly, make_queue returns a pair of ChannelReader and ChannelWriter instances that wrap the queue to prevent reads (or writes) from multiple threads
template <typename T>
class SpscQueue {
    friend ChannelReader<T>;
    friend ChannelWriter<T>;
    public:
    static std::pair<ChannelReader<T>, ChannelWriter<T>> make_queue(size_t size) {
        if (!std::__has_single_bit(size)) throw "";
        std::shared_ptr<SpscQueue<T>> queue_ptr(new SpscQueue<T>(size));
        return std::make_pair(ChannelReader<T>(queue_ptr), ChannelWriter<T>(queue_ptr));
    }
    ~SpscQueue() {
        delete[] data;
    }
    private:
    SpscQueue (size_t _size): data(new T[_size]()), size(_size) {}
    alignas(64) T* data;
    const size_t size;
    alignas(64) std::atomic<size_t> read_idx{0};
    alignas(64) std::atomic<size_t> write_idx{0};
};

// wrapper class that allows ONE thread to read from a SPSC queue
template <typename T>
class ChannelReader {
    friend SpscQueue<T>;
    public:
    // attempt to read from the queue, returning the value if successful, and std::nullopt otherwise
    std::optional<T> try_get_next() {
        size_t read_idx = queue->read_idx;
        size_t write_idx = cached_write_idx;
        if (write_idx <= read_idx) {
            write_idx = queue->write_idx;
            cached_write_idx = write_idx;
        }
        if (write_idx <= read_idx) {
            return std::nullopt;
        } else {
            queue->read_idx++;
            return std::move(queue->data[read_idx % queue->size]);
        }
    }
    ChannelReader(const ChannelReader&) = delete;
    ChannelReader& operator=(const ChannelReader&) = delete;
    ChannelReader(ChannelReader&&) = default;
    ChannelReader& operator=(ChannelReader&&) = default;
    private:
    ChannelReader(std::shared_ptr<SpscQueue<T>> ptr): queue(ptr) {}
    std::shared_ptr<SpscQueue<T>> queue;
    alignas(64) size_t cached_write_idx{0};
};

// wrapper class that allows ONE thread to write to a SPSC queue
template <typename T>
class ChannelWriter {
    friend SpscQueue<T>;
    public:
    // attempt to write to the queue, returns true if the write was successful, and false otherwise
    bool try_write_next(const T& obj) {
        size_t read_idx = cached_read_idx;
        size_t write_idx = queue->write_idx;
        if (write_idx >= read_idx + queue->size) {
            read_idx = queue->read_idx;
            cached_read_idx = read_idx;          
        }
        if (write_idx >= read_idx + queue->size) {
            return false;
        } else {
            queue->data[write_idx % queue->size] = obj;
            ++queue->write_idx;
            return true;
        }
    }
    ChannelWriter(const ChannelWriter&) = delete;
    ChannelWriter& operator=(const ChannelWriter&) = delete;
    ChannelWriter(ChannelWriter&&) = default;
    ChannelWriter& operator=(ChannelWriter&&) = default;
    private:
    ChannelWriter(std::shared_ptr<SpscQueue<T>> ptr): queue(ptr) {}
    std::shared_ptr<SpscQueue<T>> queue;
    alignas(64) size_t cached_read_idx{0};
};

main.cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include "../include/spsc_queue.hpp"

namespace chrono = std::chrono;

int main() {
  std::atomic<bool> latch{false};
  auto [reader, writer] = SpscQueue<int>::make_queue(512);
  std::thread reader_thread([_reader = std::move(reader), &latch]() mutable {
    latch.wait(false);
    std::cerr << "Starting reader...\n";
    int last_val = -1;
    while (last_val != 100'000'000 - 1) {
      if (auto data = _reader.try_get_next()) {
        if (*data != last_val + 1) {
          std::cerr << "Oh no! last value was: " << last_val
                    << " but this value is " << *data << '\n';
          std::exit(1);
        }
        last_val = *data;
        // std::cerr << last_val << " Read\n";
      }
    }
  });
  std::thread writer_thread([_writer = std::move(writer), &latch]() mutable {
    latch.wait(false);
    std::cerr << "Starting writer...\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100'000'000; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; !_writer.try_write_next(i); ++j) {
        constexpr int yield_frequency = 1 << 0;
        if (j % yield_frequency)
          std::this_thread::yield();
      }
      // std::cerr << "writer wrote value" << i << '\n';
      // if (i == 10'000'000) std::exit(1);
    }
  });
  std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
  {
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    latch = true;
    latch.notify_all();
    reader_thread.join();
    writer_thread.join();
    auto finish = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed_seconds =
        chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(finish - start).count();
    std::cout << elapsed_seconds << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}


The code doesn't look like a lock free reader writer queue.  When writing C++ concurrent code, you should describe as clearly as you can what each method is intended to do, and why this results in correct behaviour overall.  This permits readers to (a) validate your plan is valid and  b) validate your code follows your plan.  Instead you want people to deduce your plan from your code, prove to themselves that deduced plan is correct, then validate your code against the imagined plan.  Which is thousands of times harder, millions if you have a silly typo.

Wait, maybe you intend for your code to only ever support 1 reader and 1 writer at a time?!  That would explain some gaps in the design.  But then why are you using shared ptrs when there is a clear ownership option?

Also, some code implies a circular buffer, others ignores the possibility?  Not sure what is.ip with that.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont 1) Could you elaborate on this? Just documentation for each method? 2) SPSC stands for single producer single consumer, I would expect that to imply one reader, one writer (I've edited the post to use the full form instead of the acronym if that helps) 3) Where is circular buffer not implied?

Well, you do linear comparisons of indexes.  I guess you are relying on 2^64 being infinity?  A robust concurrent algorithm should have an attempt at a proof of correctness.  In your case, you may be copying someone else's algorithm (with its implied proof of correctness) and relying on that for your own correctness?

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont 1) Yes, I'm assuming that the indexes (or is it indices? English is weird sometimes) never overflow. On 64-bit machines IIRC it isn't possible for the indexes to overflow without running the program continuously for quite a few years. That being said it would be a good idea to eventually deal with overflow.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont 2) The basic idea for the SPSC queue design I'm using is based off of various resources online, I don't have a proof of correctness though. To prove correctness would it be sufficient to prove the following: a) an element cannot be read twice without a write in between, b) an element cannot be written twice without a read in between, c) if any element B is inserted after element A, element B is read after element A

My conclusion is that you are far too blase about correctness to write multi-threaded code, let alone lock-free code.  I'd advise you stop doing it.  I guarantee with at least 20 to 1 odds that any such code you write will have bugs that won't be found for at least a year after you deploy it.  Finding said bugs won't be possible by reading your code without building said proofs, which would be harder than just throwing the code out and starting from scratch.  Ahmed found one bug in your code: I guarantee there are more, and I also claim I am unable to find them in code written the way you did.

Multi-threaded code is hard to get right, and hard to verify as being right.  To have any hope of correctness in my experience you have to start with a high level description of what is going on, turn that into a proof (of at least moderate rigor).  Then write the methods, and prove they correspond to the proven correct operations (with at least moderate rigor).  If you don't do that, there will be race conditions and other problems in every concurrent code base I have ever looked at in my entire life.  These problems often occur as bugs found years after the code is in production.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont 1) How would you suggest I write my code? 2) This is just code written out of curiosity, it's not going to be used in production

I suggest you start by (1) writing a high level description of what you are doing, (2) a somewhat-rigorous proof that this high level description is correct, (3) translate this into actual code, (4) a somewhat-rigorous proof that the actual code corresponds to the high level description.  And that the high level description and semi-rigorous proof remain intact alongside the code.  Usually this involves iteration, as the first high level description won't be easy to translate into code provably; so you take the implementation and try to write a high level description from it, etc.

220231 - 219718 = 513 and the circular buffer size is 512, so the writer and the reader are racing over that last value .... you are incrementing the read index before reading the value, the writer could overwrite the value that the reader is going to read.
queue->read_idx++; // tell writer data is already read
// writer modifies data here
return std::move(queue->data[read_idx % queue->size]); // read new data

the solution is to read the value before you do the increment, same as you do when writing, first write the value then increment the write index.
auto result = std::move(queue->data[read_idx % queue->size]);
++queue->read_idx;
return result;


It looks like the (read_idx + 1) leads to an off-by-one error, replacing that with read_idx works perfectly though. I've made an edit to fix this, once that gets approved I'll accept this answer. Thanks for your help!
